# implemenatation of glulookat inside and outside the glPushMatrix?

Tags: c++, opengl

I knew what the purpose of using gluLookAt(...) , glPushMatrix and other basic transformational stuff in opengl. I am stuck in these piece of code. When i implement the glulookat(.....) inside the glPushMatrix() after setting the appropriate requirement for the opengl. The code works fine and on the keypress the cube gets rendered with appropriate rotation but when i implement the gluLookAt(....) outside the glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(), things got crazy. The cube shows the abnormal behaviour and finally it gets 
disappeared from the screen.

```
gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);          
glPushMatrix();

//gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);       
glRotatef(xRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    // Front Face
    // White
    glColor3ub((GLubyte) 255, (GLubyte)255, (GLubyte)255);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);

    // Yellow
    glColor3ub((GLubyte) 255, (GLubyte)255, (GLubyte)0);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);

    // Red
    glColor3ub((GLubyte) 255, (GLubyte)0, (GLubyte)0);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);

    // Magenta
    glColor3ub((GLubyte) 255, (GLubyte)0, (GLubyte)255);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);


// Back Face
    // Cyan
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Green
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Black
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

// Top Face
    // Cyan
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

    // White
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);

    // Magenta
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);

    // Blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

// Bottom Face
    // Green
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Yellow
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);

    // Red
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);

    // Black
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

// Left face
    // White
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);

    // Cyan
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Green
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Yellow
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);

// Right face
    // Magenta
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,50.0f);

    // Blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Black
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,-50.0f);

    // Red
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f,-50.0f,50.0f);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

`gluLookAt` mulitplies the currently topmost element of the active matrix stack with a look-at matrix and replaces the topmost element with this.

Push and Pop are standard stack operations. Push creates a copy of the topmost element and pushes it on the top of the stack, pop removes it.

So any changes you do within a push-pop block get reverted with the pop operation. But outside of a stack frame (push-pop) the changes will accumulate. If you put a `glLoadIdentity` before the `gluLookAt` outside of the push-pop, it will work as well, but that is, because you reset the matrix to a sane value instead of working on top of what's been there from the previous rendering.

Comment: Well i got it and my code works but can i have a brief insight insight into the matrix manipulation by gluLookAt() when it is outside the glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(). I want to know about the sane value.

Comment: @AbhayaSinghPandey: The behavior of `gluLookAt` always is the same. It performs the calculation/assignment `M = M · L`, where `M` is the top element of the matrix stack, and `L` is the look-at matrix derived from the parameters. It's always the same. The "magic" lies in the stack. You may think the stack as an array of matrices, with the very last element of the array being the "top" of the stack. A *push* operations can be thought as `stack.append(stack.last())`, i.e. it creates a copy of the topmost element and appends, (pushes) it onto the stack.

Comment: @AbhayaSinghPandey: In the calculation above `M = M · L` you can substitute `M := stack.last()`. So when you push the stack you create a "protected" frame to work in. And when poping it, you revert to the state the stack was before the push. Now in OpenGL the matrix stacks are initialized with a single identity matrix. When you call `glPushMatrix` this identity matrix becomes sort of "protected" from things happening. The matching pop reverts to that identity matrix.

Comment: @AbhayaSinghPandey: But when you don't introduce the stack frames, your `gluLookAt` will multiply on whatever there already is on the stack. And if you don't explicitly reinitialize to identity inbetween that would be the result of the previous `gluLookAt`, which ends you in a recursion `L_n = L_{0} · L_{1} · … · L_{n-2} · L_{n-1}`, where n is the number of your drawing iterations. Obviously those look-at transformed chained together will shift your objects out of view.